# Bravenet Guestbook CSS

Tags: html, css

I am embedding a free Bravenet Guestbook (http://pub20.bravenet.com)onto a page of a site I am currently building.

You can see it here: http://portabledogpotty.com/customer-reviews.html.

As you can see if you go the site, the guestbook is aligned to the left. I want it to be centered. I have tried various ways of trying to move it over with using the site css, to no avail. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong, or if I actually need to be editing the Bravenet specific css file, which if that is the case, how do I access it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of the markup that shows the problem here. A link to your site, which can change or disappear tomorrow, helps no one in the future.

Comment: put margin:0 auto; to div with id: #bn-guestbook-1-1-1641477518-wrapper.

Comment: Hi Rob. I'll definitely keep that in mind from here on out. Though...not really sure what code would be ideal to post in this situation...

Answer (score 0):

You can horizontally align something like that by defining a width and setting margin left and right to `auto`.

Since `#bn-guestbook-1-1-1641477518` already has `width: 700px;` all you have to do is add this

```
#bn-guestbook-1-1-1641477518 {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael! The only problem with this is that the id "bn-guestbook-1-1-1641477518" is on a different css file from Bravenet which I don't know how to access. If I put the code you shared on the css file for the website, it doens't do anything.

Comment: @sstoker how do you add the guestbook to the page in the first place? Is it via this tag? `<div id="guestbook"; margin-left="100px";> <script src="http://apps.bravenet.com/go.js?service=guestbook;id=1;usernum=1641477518" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script></div>`? If so, you can try changing `<div id="guestbook"; margin-left="100px";>` to `<div id="guestbook" style="width:700px;margin:auto;">`

Comment: @sstoker sweet!